# How to define filters in plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, plupload

I use plupload.
Plupload allows me to select files which extensions did not defined in settings.
For example I can select and upload .rar or .txt files.
But I do not define these extensions in filters.

```
$(".uploadDocs").click(function () 
{
    //var extensions = $(this).data("ext");

    $("#pluploadUploader").pluploadQueue(
    {
        runtimes: 'html5',
        url: "Upload",
        filters: 
        {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: 
            [
                { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
                { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
            ]
        },
    }, 
    {
        FileUploaded: function (up, file, data) 
        {
            var out = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.response));
            uploadedFiles.push(out.UploadedFileName);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my jquery.plupload.queue.js and plupload.full.min.js versions. 
I work on a template project from themeforest. 
And I saw that my current .js files versions not up to date.
So I updated .js files to the latest version and plupload works well now.